# Golangのbuiltin moduleのソースコードの場所

Tags: go

Golangのbuiltin moduleのソースコードが見たいのですが、どこにあるのでしょうか?
[golang/go](http://github.com/golang/go)の`src/builtin/builtin.go`を見てもドキュメントのための宣言があるだけで実装ではありません。

どこにbultin moduleの実装があるのでしょうか?

Comment: [これ](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/go/types/builtins.go)です。[テストファイル](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/go/types/builtins_test.go)を見ると分かりやすいかと思います。